# Aggregate group means while ignoring zeros unless 0 is the only value

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, aggregate

Given the following data format:

```
c1 c2 c3
A  B  100  
A  B  200
A  C    0
A  C    0
D  E  550  
D  E  700
D  F  100
D  F    0
```

I want to get the mean of c3 within the group of same A and B. By using R’s `aggregate` function:

```
aggregate(c3~c1+c2, data=myData, FUN=mean)
```

I get the correct subset mean table:

```
A  B  150
A  C    0
D  E  625  
D  F   50
```

Yet, I want to exclude the mean calculation for the case if there is a value and a zero. So that the last two line of the first code;

```
D  F  100
D  F    0
```

should evaluate to:

```
D  F  100
```

Is there a way to modify the `aggregate` function? Or is there an elegant way to pre-process my data at first?

Comment: you could exclude rows in `myData`containing 0 or specific(100 here) as `aggregate(c3~c1+c2, data=myData[myData$c3 != 0 | myData$c3 != 100,], FUN=mean)`, or do you want to exclude rows in _mean_ calculated table ?

Comment: you want as well ignore the other two 0 values...A C ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could pass a custom function that searches for the condition you are mentioning (x includes zeroes and a nonzero values), and if met you return a mean of the non-zero values in the first case, otherwise you compute the standard mean as always.

```
#prepare data
df <- data.frame(c1=c("A","A","A","A","D","D","D","D"),
           c2= c("B","B","C","C","E","E","F","F"),
           c3= c(100,200,0,0,550,700,100,0))

#aggregate
aggregate(c3~c1+c2, data=df, FUN=(function(x){ifelse(sum(x==0)>0 & sum(x !=0) >0, mean(x[x>0]), mean(x))}))
      c1 c2  c3
    1  A  B 150
    2  A  C   0
    3  D  E 625
    4  D  F 100
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(myData)[,  .(c3 = if(!all(c3==0)) mean(c3[c3!=0]) else 0), .(c1, c2)]
#   c1 c2  c3
#1:  A  B 150
#2:  A  C   0
#3:  D  E 625
#4:  D  F 100
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using `aggregate`. The inner function works by indexing, and chooses whether to convert the 0 values to NA and calculate a mean with `na.rm=TRUE` or to return 0 based on whether all values are 0.

```
aggregate(c3 ~ c1 + c2, dat,
          FUN=function(x) c(mean(x * NA^(!x), na.rm=TRUE), 0)[all(x == 0) + 1L])
  c1 c2  c3
1  A  B 150
2  A  C   0
3  D  E 625
4  D  F 100
```